# Printing a class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the following class to return `rectangle(x=5,y=10,width=50,and height=100)` but I can not figure out why it is not returning this using in Python3 and IDLE. I also tried the `print` function but it didn't work either:

```
class rectangle:

   def point(self):
     self.x = 5
     self.y = 10
     self.width = 50
     self.height = 100
     return("rectangle"(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height))
```

Answer (score 2):

To *print* an object in Python you should define a [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method:

```
class rectangle:

   def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, width=0, height=0):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.width = width
       self.height = height

   def __str__(self):
       return "rectangle (x=%s, y=%s, width=%s, height=%s)" % (self.x, 
                                                               self.y, 
                                                               self.width, 
                                                               self.height)

r = rectangle(5, 10, 50, 100)
print r
```

Outputs:

```
rectangle (x=5, y=10, width=50, height=100)
```

- Check the documentation for the explanation of the [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) and [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__).
- The class constructor for an object in Python is the [`__init__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to treat a string as a callable. If you want to return a new instance of the *class*, then call the class:

```
class rectangle:
     def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
         self.width = width
         self.height = height

     def point(self):
         self.x = 5
         self.y = 10
         self.width = 50
         self.height = 100
         return rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
```

Note that this does require that your class has a `__init__` method!

If you wanted to return a string you have to use string formatting instead:

```
return "rectangle({}, {}, {}, {})".format(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
```

Comment: While this is syntactically correct is doesn't teach good Python OOP practices. The encapsulation of the `point` method doesn't make sense.